# Stack Exchange interface is displayed without any styling

Tags: discussion

I have a problem in using the Stack Exchange network. I use 2 computers, which are in my house and workplace respectively. Last time I accessed the Stack Overflow homepage for the first time at my workplace, but the interface was abnormal like in the picture below. This problem happens on all Stack Exchange network sites, not just Stack Overflow.

This interface has little visibility, and I cannot even find the login button. But with the computer in my house, I can access it no problem. So currently when I want to use the Stack Exchange network I have to first initiate remote control. Of course this is nonsense.

I don't know why and I couldn't find anything regarding this on the internet. Coworkers of mine don't use Stack Exchange so this is very irritating. I tried everything I could, but it doesn't work at all.
So if you know any solution please tell me.

[image: Stack Overflow home page without any styling]

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: @iggy890 my home computer's OS is win11, but that of workplace is win10

Comment: Are the web browsers the same?

Comment: @Spencer I tried accessing chrome and edge on both computer. But in my workplace the result was same. I tried again after erasing cash, but didn't worked

Comment: Check Browser Tools, looks like a CSS file is getting blocked.